# Setting a virtualbox with a functional shared folder

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, windows-xp, shared-folders, guest-additions

I know there are multiple questions about this already, but none of the answers clearly helped me achieve my objective: To run Windows XP as guest within Virtual box with Ubuntu 16.04 as host, **with a functional shared folder between host and guest**.

I need a step by step approach to what I need to do, in which OS (host or guest), which version and in which installation order, starting from zero, no virtual box related packages installed and no additional repositories added.

What I do know is that:

-I need to install Virtual box

-I need to install  Virtual box guest additions that are compatible with the virtual box version installed.

-I need to set a shared folder in virtual box (I know how to do it)

-Windows XP must recognise the folder

So far I tried multiple times with multiple versions in multiple installation orders, but ended with windows XP not showing the shared folder, even with auto-mount on the shared folder.

Running on the guest cmd:

net use x: \vboxsvr\MySharedFiles -p

Always returned "System error 53. Network path not found."

Comment: Try `net use x: \\vboxsvr\MySharedFiles /persistent:yes` (note the double-backslash).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same system error but my guest OS is Windows 10. 
My issue was the wrong version of the VBox Extension Pack on the Ubuntu host.

Check your VBox version via 'Help' - 'About' and the version of your extension pack in 'Files' - 'Preferences'.

After I did a downgrade on my host and reinstalled the Guest Additions in my Win 10 guest my shared folder showed up even without running the 'net use' command.

Hope it helps you if your still facing the issue!

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your post, but can you please elaborate on it a bit?  A little Step by Step tutorial would be ideal.  Explaining how to downgrade successfully, and things to watch out for would be ideal :)